# Why the b in sentence 'int*a,b;' is considered as an int type instead of pointer to int type in C language?

Tags: c, point

We know that `int *p;` means declaring a pointer `p` to int data and `int a,b;` means declaring two int variables.

If we consider `int *` as a data type which means the pointer to int data, then the `int*a,b;` would means that declaring two pointers.

But it is not consistent with my code result.

This is my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=10;
    int * a,b;
    a=&i;
    b=&i;
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    printf("%d",*b);
    return 0;
}
```

The code failed to compile.I removed the `*` in front of the `b` and then the code ran successfully.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=10;
    int * a,b;
    a=&i;
    b=&i;
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

This seemed that `b` was not the pointer and it was the int variable.

Since we couldn't see the `*` as a notation which is independent of `p`,**does this mean that `int* p` doesn't equal to `int *p` although the result are same?**

Comment: `int* a, b;` does not declare two pointers to `int`. Instead it declares a pointer `a` and and integer `b`. If you include the `'*'` with the  variable that becomes immediately obvious, e.g. `int *a, b;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the e.g. at the end of your comment is probably a typo, i think you meant to type: int *a, *b;

Comment: @HarryK., nope, `int *a, b;` was intentional. One pointer-to `int` and one `int`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ah ok, I thought  you wanted to show OP how to declare 2 pointers in the same line (English isn't my 1st language :) ).

Comment: @HarryK. No worries. Not like I've never misread or confused the issues before ... at least not much more than once daily for good measure.